# pd.DataFrame(column=) is causing a TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas

Hey y'all this is my first time using a web scraper and I haven't used python in a while so bare with me. I am trying to use this code to collect data from pro football reference for the top QBs from 2000-2022 I can download each QB's yearly stats from a leaderboard each year. The actual column for the year does not download so it is is impossible to know which year of the QB's stats you are looking for. Unfortunately I tried to append the year on every row, and I added a column for year to be placed in the the column headers. Unfortunately when I try to run this code the error:

**TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()**

appears and I believe it is referring to where I specify columns = in the last line of my code. If anyone has any recommendations I would love to hear them please!

```
    qb_stats = []
    # Collect table headers
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    data['year'] = None
    
    years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 ]
    
    for year in years:
      # URL of page
      url = f"https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{yl}/passing.htm"
      
      # Open URL and pass to BeautifulSoup
      html = urlopen(url)
      stats_page = BeautifulSoup(html)
      
    
      # Collect table rows
      rows = stats_page.findAll('tr')[1:]

      # Get stats from each row
      column_headers = stats_page.findAll('tr')[0]
      column_headers = [i.getText() for i in column_headers.findAll(['th','td'])]
      column_headers.append('Years')

    
      for i in range(0,len(rows)):
        qb_stats.append([col.getText() for col in rows[i].findAll(['td'])])
      qb_stats = list(qb_stats)
      qb_stats.append(year)

    # Create DataFrame from our scraped data
      data = pd.DataFrame(data = qb_stats, columns = column_headers[1:])
```

Comment: `qb_stats.append(year)` <- year is an int. then, you create a DataFrame from `qb_stats`, which now has a mix of lists and ints. did you mean to append `year` to `qb_stats[-1]`? or somewhere else?

Comment: what is the type of `rows` when you loop through `range(0,len(rows))`? If it is an `int`, you cannot do `len()`, just do `range(0, rows)`. Because the error is straightforward a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things,

1. 'yl' is not defined in your code for `url = f"https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{yl}/passing.htm"`
2. Let pandas parse the table

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
years = range(2000, 2023)    
for year in years:
  # URL of page
  print(year)
  url = f"https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{year}/passing.htm"
  df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
  df['Years'] = year
  df_list.append(df)
  
results = pd.concat(df_list)
results = results[results['Rk'].ne('Rk')]
```

**Output:**

```
print(results)
    Rk             Player   Tm Age Pos   G  ...   NY/A   ANY/A  4QC  GWD Years  QBR
0    1    Peyton Manning*  IND  24  QB  16  ...   7.25    7.22    2    3  2000  NaN
1    2       Jeff Garcia*  SFO  30  QB  16  ...   7.05    7.34  NaN  NaN  2000  NaN
2    3       Elvis Grbac*  KAN  30  QB  15  ...   6.87    6.75    3    3  2000  NaN
3    4  Daunte Culpepper*  MIN  23  QB  16  ...   7.39    7.28    3    4  2000  NaN
4    5        Brett Favre  GNB  31  QB  16  ...   5.83    5.31    0    4  2000  NaN
..  ..                ...  ...  ..  ..  ..  ...    ...     ...  ...  ...   ...  ...
34  34       Dak Prescott  DAL  29  QB   1  ...   3.90    2.45  NaN  NaN  2022  NaN
35  35        Jordan Love  GNB  24  QB   1  ...  13.00   13.00  NaN  NaN  2022  NaN
36  36        Braden Mann  NYJ  25   P   2  ...  17.00   17.00  NaN  NaN  2022  NaN
37  37     Trace McSorley  ARI  27  QB   1  ...   0.80    0.80  NaN  NaN  2022  NaN
38  38      DeeJay Dallas  SEA  24  RB   2  ...   0.00  -45.00  NaN  NaN  2022  NaN

[2274 rows x 32 columns]
```